# Hero image size for different displays

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm in the process of building a website featuring a hero image. At present the image is 1560px wide, but I worry that it's not enough for some big displays out there. I would rather not have the edges of the photo be seen.

At the same time, I don't want to have too large an image for mobile users to have to load.

What is the best compromise here? Are you supposed to load different images depending on display size?

edit: Sorry I should have said I know how to make the image fill 100% of the width, but what I'm worried about there is the lack of resolution. I guess what I'm asking is whether for best practices you are supposed to load different images for different displays?

Comment: Adding width 100% to img tag. Could be the better solution.

Comment: You _can_ load different images depending on display size if you want. See [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not giving us any hints of how you are creating the hero image. Is it a `<img>` or is it as a background of a div, but this is **how I usually do** such "full width" hero images.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url('http://www.redcross.org/images/MEDIA_CustomProductCatalog/m17844381_TheHero_763x260_PRE.JPG');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.content {
  width: 480px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This is content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about resolution, then the best way would be to load different images for different window sizes. If you are loading the images via css then it is easier, but if you are using an `img` tag then you might have to go with Mr Lister's comment on using the `<picture>` tag. However, `<picture>` is experimental and old browsers will not support it.

Another way would be to use a mixture of both HTML and CSS.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        .below-1200px,
        .below-800px {
            display: none;
    }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
        .above-1200px,
        .below-800px {
            display: none;
    }
    }
        .above-1200px,
        .below-1200px {
            display: none;
    }
```

```html
<img class="above-1200px" src="http://placehold.it/1200x150"/>
    <img class="below-1200px" src="http://placehold.it/800x150"/>
    <img class="below-800px" src="http://placehold.it/400x150"/>
```

Comment: The solution with `display:none` loads all three images, so don't use that if you're concerned about bandwidth.

Comment: Absolutely right, @MrLister, my apologies for not mentioning it in my answer.